# Force enabled look to readonly input with bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app using [bootstrap.css](http://getbootstrap.com/) for the design. I have a readonly input which looks like disabled because of bootstrap (cursor not allowed, background color grey etc...). I would like the input to look enabled with readonly activated.

How can I do that?

**edit** (adding more code):

Header:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='myApp')
  head
    title=title
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/bootstrap.min-3.1.1.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css')
```

My input: `input.form-control(readonly, placeholder='jj-mm-aaaa')`

My stylus (style.css):

```
input[readonly]
  background-color: #fff
```

Comment: line #1725 .form-control[readonly], you can change it, or overwrite

Comment: Other than [overriding](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5802/) the `[disabled]`/`[readonly]` styles I don't think they provide a solution to this.

Comment: @falcon I would like to keep the bootstrap intact...

Comment: So try !important clause

Comment: @falcon What is it? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Adrift Are you sure I cant't force the style in any way?

Comment: @ncohen: I'm 99% sure.

Comment: Do you have a custom CSS file in addition to bootstrap.css?

Comment: Also, please post your code and what you tried already.

Comment: yes, I do have a custom CSS file.

Comment: @quoo see my edit for code

Comment: That is jade code, what custom CSS have you tried?

Comment: There is one another question to you. Do you want to use new styles only once, or as a "part" of bootstrap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your custom css is included after the boostrap.css, place the following code in your custom css file

```
input[readonly] {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* any other styles */
}
```

If you only want to apply this style to specific read only inputs, add a class "exampleclass" to those inputs, and then use:

```
input[readonly].exampleclass {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It's better to take advantage of how CSS works rather than just stick !importants everywhere. The custom CSS should be included after bootstrap.css anyway so that the custom CSS does not get overridden by anything in bootstrap.css

Comment: Is your custom css include after your boostrap.css include?

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: My bad, I forgot the form-control class! Now it works...thanks

Comment: Assuming from @ncohen's comment that he meant `input[readonly].form-control { background-color: #fff; }`, which worked flawlessly for me.